# Why didn't reverse grep work to filter out "Operation not permitted" from find results?

Tags: terminal, command-line, unix, error, search

When I want to reverse grep the words in macOS 13.2 like this:

```
$ sudo find / -name "libpq.dylib" | grep -v "Operation not permitted"
find: /Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC: Operation not permitted
```

The result still contains `Operation not permitted` result. Why didn't the reverse grep work as expected? What should I do to reverse grep the words?

Comment: Side note: You seem to be traversing the entire file system root `/`. However, since you're looking for a `dylib`, I suggest try most likely places such as `/usr`, `/Applications`, `/System/Applications`, `/System/Library`, and `/Library`. And `/opt/local` if MacPorts is installed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`find` (like most Unix utilities) sends errors to `stderr`, the pipe listens on `stdout` only though. So you need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` to make it work.

```
sudo find / -name 'libpq.dylib' 2>&1 | grep -v 'Operation not permitted'
```

Comment: This will hide files like `foo/Operation not permitted/libpq.dylib` though. Unlikely, sure, but not impossible.

Answer (score 9):

While the first answer is certainly correct, it may be that what the user really wants is simply to drop all of the stderr from the output, which can be done via

```
sudo find / -name 'libpq.dylib' 2>/dev/null
```